# Filter Change the color of the word in the sentence angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to change the color of the word in the sentence How can i do that?

Controller code:

```
app.controller("myController",function($scope){

                $scope.phrase="This is a bad phrase";
    });

    app.filter('censor', function(){
        return function(input){
            var cWords = ['bad', 'evil', 'dark'];
            var out = input;
            for(var i=0; i<cWords.length;i++){
                out = out.replace(cWords[i], <span class="blue"></span>);
            }
            return out;
        };
    })
```

My view:

```
{{phrase | censor}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to bind html in your filter, you need to use ngSanitize and binding with the directive: ng-bind-html instead of {{ }}, like this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="ctrl.phrase | censor"></p>
```

In your js file you need to check if the phrase contain any of the words you want to filter out, then update the phrase.

```
angular
  .module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.phrase = 'This is a bad phrase';
  })
  .filter('censor', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var cWords = ['bad', 'evil', 'dark'];
      var splitPhrase = input.split(' ');
      var out = splitPhrase.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        if (cWords.indexOf(curr) > -1) {
          acc.push('<span class="blue">' + curr + '</span>');
        } else {
          acc.push(curr);
        }

        return acc;
      }, []);

      return out.join(' ');
    }
  });
```

You can find an example here: http://jsbin.com/koxekoq/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you but i want to This is a <span class="blue">bad phrase</span>
I wanna make syntax highlighter

Comment: I've been updating the example

Comment: thank you my friend last question I want to make cWords[0] color red, cWords[2] blue ? How do I do it?

Comment: You can simply do that by using an object for cWords. I've updated the example, here you can finde the latest: http://jsbin.com/koxekoq/edit?html,js,output

Comment: sorry i have a problem. http://jsbin.com/xoqiqeriya/edit?html,js,output bad\nbad\n not work

Comment: it's normal, because in the script you check the "perfect match" with the word (bad for example). So, when you compare if "bad" is equal to "bad\n" the result is false.

Comment: i want to read textarea line by line so when enter is pressed the "bad" color is not blue